# Number of bits used in an image

Tags: matlab, bit

How can I get the number of bits used in an image in `Matlab`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean the Bit Depth of the image (i.e. how many bits are used for encoding one pixel) try using the Image PRocessing Toolbox's function `imfinfo`

[Link to the Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imfinfo.html)

Here's how you could use it:

```
info = imfinfo('your_image.jpg') # put your filename, matlab recognizes many image formats
bitdepth = info.BitDepth
```